# How are my functions connected to the right member function

Tags: c++

so basically I'm learning about game programming from this book, I'm currently on the part where it is explaining where is a data member is a pointer which points to object stored on the heap. it then does a couple of member functions such as destroy/copy or assign to another object.

so basically what I am trying to understand is when i am calling the three functions "`testDestructor()`"/ "`testCopyConstructor(Critter aCopy)` " and "`testAssignmentOp()`" is automatically going to the right member function, it might sound silly but unless I am misreading something, I don't see the book explaining how each fucntion is going to the correct member function.

I don't know its 11:30pm and maybe my brain is melted but I've reread this whole (few pages) detailed explanation of whats going on in the program three times and i cannot make heads or tails of how its correctly using the right member function without some kind of "connection"? perhaps I am missing something rudimentary.

P.S I understand what is happening with the code itself, I just don't know how the functions are calling the correct member functions

```
/Heap Data Member
//Demonstrates an object with a dynamically allocated data member

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Critter
{
public: 
Critter(const string& name = "", int age = 0);  
~Critter();                   //destructor prototype   
Critter(const Critter& c);    //copy constructor prototype
Critter& Critter::operator=(const Critter& c);  //overloaded assignment op
void Greet() const; 

private:
string* m_pName;
int m_Age;
};

Critter::Critter(const string& name, int age)
{
cout << "Constructor called\n";
m_pName = new string(name);
m_Age = age;  
}

Critter::~Critter()                        //destructor definition
{
   cout << "Destructor called\n";
   delete m_pName;
}

Critter::Critter(const Critter& c)        //copy constructor definition
{
  cout << "Copy Constructor called\n";
  m_pName = new string(*(c.m_pName));
  m_Age = c.m_Age;
}

Critter& Critter::operator=(const Critter& c)  //overloaded assignment op   def
{
  cout << "Overloaded Assignment Operator called\n";
  if (this != &c)
  {
      delete m_pName;
      m_pName = new string(*(c.m_pName));
      m_Age = c.m_Age;
  }
  return *this;
}

void Critter::Greet() const
{
   cout << "I'm " << *m_pName << " and I'm " << m_Age << " years old. ";
   cout << "&m_pName: " << cout << &m_pName << endl;
}

void testDestructor();
void testCopyConstructor(Critter aCopy);
void testAssignmentOp();

int main()
{
  testDestructor();
  cout << endl;

  Critter crit("Poochie", 5);
  crit.Greet();
  testCopyConstructor(crit);
  crit.Greet();
  cout << endl;

  testAssignmentOp();

  return 0;
}

void testDestructor()
{
  Critter toDestroy("Rover", 3);
  toDestroy.Greet();
}

void testCopyConstructor(Critter aCopy)  
{
  aCopy.Greet();
}

void testAssignmentOp()
{
  Critter crit1("crit1", 7);
  Critter crit2("crit2", 9);
  crit1 = crit2;
  crit1.Greet();  
  crit2.Greet();
  cout << endl;

  Critter crit3("crit", 11);
  crit3 = crit3;
  crit3.Greet();
}
```

Comment: "a data member is a pointer which points to object stored on the heap" wat

Comment: perhaps I should have written it as "The data member which I am using is a pointer which is pointing to an object stored in the heap".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you are asking, but:

The *assignment operator* is called when you use `=` in an expression, such as in your code:

```
crit1 = crit2;
crit3 = crit3;
```

Not to be confused with using the `=` symbol in a declaration (which you don't do anyway).

A *constructor* is called when you try to create an object, such as:

```
Critter crit2( "crit1", 7 );    // constructor
```

Other lines might look like:

```
Critter crit4;             // default constructor
Critter crit5(crit3);      // copy-constructor
```

If a constructor takes one argument that is another object of the same type, it's called a copy-constructor. This is just a terminology thing, there's no more fundamental distinction between copy-constructors and other constructors.

In your function `void testCopyConstructor(Critter aCopy)` , you can see that it has a parameter `Critter aCopy`. When you pass the argument `crit` to the function, it is like you create the parameter using the function argument:

```
Critter aCopy(crit);    // equivalent
```

so calling this function will initialize `aCopy` using its copy-constructor.

A *destructor* is called whenever a local object goes out of scope, so when the `}` is reached at the end of `testDestructor`, then object `toDestroy` is destroyed.

Comment: Oh ok, i understand what you are saying now, and how each function is calling the correct constructor, sorry when i was reading the book it missed this step explaining this so when each constructor was being called correctly, I wasn't sure how it was doing so

I think what I was misunderstanding properly is these are natural things the compiler does when you don't create your own, so I never really new that these instances in my code calls these constructors like shown in the code, so when i was having this done & displayed it made no sense to me

Thanks for explaining very simply for me

Answer (score 0):

> what I am trying to understand is when i am calling the three functions "testDestructor()"/ "testCopyConstructor(Critter aCopy) " and "testAssignmentOp()" how is it automatically going to the right member function, it might sound silly but unless I am misreading something, I don't see the book explaining how each fucntion is going to the correct member function.

Instance (non-`static`) member functions are always passed a hidden pointer as their first argument - explicitly available within the class under the name `this` - which refers to the target object. This means that when a member function is invoked on/in any instance of a class (object), any in-scope references to member variables will be targeted to `this` instance via the pointer.

(This well documented and did not really need a new question. Hopefully your book mentions it elsewhere!)